# Guiding zucchini growth off edge of raised bed

Tags: raised-beds, zucchini

I have a 4' by 8' raised bed that I tend to overfill. :)  I have two zucchini plants that are growing very nicely.

To prevent them from covering other plants in the bed, I was thinking of guiding their growth off the edge of the bed so that they will extend over the ground next to the bed instead of covering other plants.  The bed is about a foot high.

Do you think that will harm the zucchini plants at all?

EDIT:

I'm adding some photos to confirm that Graham's advice was good!  I put a little box next to the bed to make the drop a little more gradual.  The zucchini split into three branches, and the neighbors are scared it will take over the neighborhood. :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's great to hear, and they look really pretty. We always appreciate an update, so thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this, and it'll be fine. Or you could stake, or trellis it too.

This link talks of staking using rebar, and removing leaves below the fruit when it is removed.

http://www.mysquarefootgarden.net/pruning-zucchini/